# Fragment inside Drawer

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I want to add a fragment for a sliding drawer in DrawerLayout. Means the last child of DrawerLayout is to be a fragment. And When I click on Drawer ico, the fragment to be visible in Drawer.
But When i try, I couldn't get the view of the fragment in Activity. 
Please help me for doing it.

Thanks 
Jomia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

In layout,

```
  <fragment
  android:name="com.example.fragments.MyFragment "
  android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="240dp"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

In activity,

MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.left_drawer);
View fragmentView = myFragment .getView();

Then I just use this view in onPrepareOptionsMenu for drawer.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
  { 
      boolean isDrawerOpen= dLayout.isDrawerOpen(fragmentView );    
      if(isDrawerOpen)
          menu.findItem(R.id.drawer).setVisible(false);
      else
          menu.findItem(R.id.drawer).setVisible(true);
      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Thats all...